# Is $\int^a\frac{\sqrt{x^3-a^3}}{\sqrt{x-a}}dx $ equal to $0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Obviously this is not a nice integral for us to just analytically compute.

My question is whether this integral is $0$ or whether it is undefined and how we would should what it is? Of course, if $x=a$ then the integrand is undefined and if $x<a$ then the integrand is not real. I'm not sure if this has any relevance to this problem?

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{x^3-a^3}}{\sqrt{x-a}}=\sqrt{x^2+ax+a^2} $. Moreover, the INDEFINITE integral is not uniquely defined

Comment: Please don't use \displaystyle, nor \dfrac, etc in the title of any post.  It is great to use in the body of posts.

Comment: An indefinite integral is only defined up to a $+C$.  So obviously the answer is not $0$.

Comment: I think the OP meant a definite integral after all. He just missed to write the lower end. But I realized this only after posting my answer. It's not quite clear anyway.

Comment: @peter.petrov sorry for the confusion, the $a$ is the upper limit and the lower limit (I believe) is $-\infty$. Essentially this is part of a larger problem I have where I need to evaluate $\int_a^b\frac{\sqrt{x^3-a^3}}{\sqrt{x-a}}$ where $x\in(a,b]$

Comment: The (definite) integral of a positive function cannot be zero (It must be a positive number, possibly infinity)

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments and answers, you simply need to compute
$$I=\int\sqrt{t^2+at+a^2}\,dt$$
Start completing the square
$$t^2+at+a^2=\left(t+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3 a^2}{4}$$ So, let $$t=\frac{a \left(3 u-\sqrt{3}\right)}{2 \sqrt{3}}\implies I=\frac{3}{4} a^2\int \sqrt{u^2+1}\,du$$  which is well known. One integration by parts gives
$$I=\frac{3}{8} a^2 \left(u\sqrt{u^2+1} +\sinh ^{-1}(u)\right)$$ Back to $t$
$$I=\frac{1}{4} (2 t+a) \sqrt{t^2+at+a^2}+\frac{3}{8} a^2 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 t+a}{a\sqrt{3} }\right)+C$$

Integrated between $a$ and $x$ as @J.G. did
$$J=\int_a^x\sqrt{t^2+at+a^2}\,dt=\frac{1}{4} (2 x+a) \sqrt{x^2+ax+a^2}+$$ $$\frac{3}{8} a^2 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x+a}{a\sqrt{3} }\right)-\frac{3}{8} a^2 \left(2 \sqrt{3}+\sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's interested, the unique antiderivative that vanishes at $x=a$ is$$\begin{align}\int_a^x\sqrt{t^2+at+a^2}dt&=\tfrac34a^2\int_{\pi/3}^{\arctan\tfrac{1+2x/a}{\sqrt{3}}}\sec^3udu\\&=\tfrac38a^2[\sec u\tan u+\ln|\sec u+\tan u|]_{\pi/3}^{\arctan\tfrac{1+2x/a}{\sqrt{3}}}\\&=\tfrac38a^2\left(\tfrac{1+2x/a}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{1+\tfrac{(1+2x/a)^2}{3}}-2\sqrt{3}+\ln\left|\tfrac{\sqrt{1+\tfrac{(1+2x/a)^2}{3}}+\tfrac{1+2x/a}{\sqrt{3}}}{2+\sqrt{3}}\right|\right)\end{align}$$(using $t=\tfrac12a(\sqrt{3}\tan u-1)$ and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed)). The most general antiderivative is the above $+C$, equal to $C$ at $x=a$.